# Searching for matches from all nodes to all nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of nodes that represent links between file system locations.  I can load all the nodes and I'm trying to link them together by looking for matches between the destination and source directories in each node.

Pseudocode query:

```
For all Interface nodes in Neo4j, 
search all other nodes for where other.sourcedir = this.destdir.  
If a match is found, create a SENDS_TO relationship from A to B.
```

Naive query:
    MATCH (a:Interface), (b:Interface) WHERE a.destdir == b.sourcedir MERGE (a)-[r:SENDS_TO]->(b)

When I run that query, Neo4j appeared to go into an infinite loop which I terminated after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this instead:

```
MATCH (a:Interface)
with a
MATCH (b:Interface)
WHERE a.destdir == b.sourcedir and a <> b
MERGE (a)-[:SENDS_TO->(b);
```

This might perform better, but the query you're running compares about every interface to every other interface.  So it seems O(n^2) to me, it's going to be slow if you had 80 frazillion nodes.  Prior to running this, you'll probably want to ensure indexes are present on `destdir` and `sourcedir`.

Comment: This was the script that ended up working:  MATCH (a:Interface)
with a
MATCH (b:Interface)
WHERE a.destdir = b.sourcedir and a <> b
MERGE (a)-[:SENDS_TO]->(b)

Comment: And even with 1400 nodes to search, it completed almost instantaneously.